# Do not take into account soft delete for blobs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a Azure Storage Account and I have enabled soft delete for blobs.

Is is possible to call instant deletion (ignore the soft deletion period) for some specific blobs?

I am using Azure.Storage.Blob v12.7.0, but DeleteBlobIfExistsAsync or DeleteAsync have no extra parameters that I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment there is no built-in feature to permanent delete blobs with enabled  soft-delete option (ignore the soft deletion period).

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/35076274-permanent-deletion-of-soft-deleted-blobs-gdpr

There is a workaround:
Disable the soft-deleted option.
Select the Blob Containers via Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, choose Active and deleted blobs.
Undelete the deleted blobs and then remove it again
Then blob is permanently deleted

This approach is described here

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/13064

You can automate the above workaround with Azure.Storage.Blob v12.7.0